# How to generate the dynamic where condition in pl/sql cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Generate the dynamic where condition in pl/sql cursor based on input values

For Example :

> Input Values : a b c values

Query Format :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure abcprocedure
   ( a IN Number,b IN Number, c IN Number )

    cursor abccursor
        IS
           select 1  
             from pqr  p 
            where ( Prepare the where condition based on a,b,c values and null checks also )
```

Comment: what condition do you want to create? Please add that in question. Suggestion, you can create a dynamic query. But actual answer will depend on the conditions that you want to create.

Comment: 1) if a=5,b=null,c=null then prepare the dynamic where condition like where data1=a  2 )  if a=5,b=7,c=null then prepare the dynamic where condition like where data1=a,data2=b -- Like wise query has to prepare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I understood the problem; no *dynamic* stuff is necessary.

For simpler testing (on my side, as I don't have your tables), on Scott's `DEPT` table, this might do the job (`par_x` is name of procedure's parameter).

```
select *
from dept
where deptno in (par_a, par_b, par_c)
   or (par_a is null and par_b is null and par_c is null);
```

If those are different columns, no problem either:

```
select * 
from dept
where (deptno = par_a or par_a is null)
  and (dname  = par_b or par_b is null)
  and (loc    = par_c or par_c is null);
```

If certain parameter isn't passed and you don't want to see that column's value, then use

```
select case when par_a is not null then deptno
            else null
       end deptno,
       --
       case when par_b is not null then dname
            else null
       end dname,
       --
       case when par_c is not null then loc
            else null
       end loc
from dept
where (deptno = par_a or par_a is null)
  and (dname  = par_b or par_b is null)
  and (loc    = par_c or par_c is null);
```

If you want to exclude the column from result set, well, that isn't that simple. If you used (for example) Oracle Apex, you could choose not to render that column. Otherwise, in pure SQL, I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. But My Acutal Question where deptno1=a and deptno2=b and deptno3=c like that

Comment: No problem; I've edited my message. Have a look, please.

Comment: I need one more suggestion. If a=null deptno=a should not be framed.

Comment: I don't quite understand ... what does "should not be framed" mean?

Comment: Should not be included

Answer (score 2):

According to your comments, I should suggest using `coalesce` in where condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM PQR P
WHERE COALESCE(A, DEPT1) = DEPT1
AND COALESCE(B, DEPT2) = DEPT2
AND COALESCE(C, DEPT3) = DEPT3;
```

`Coalesce` will take the passed parameter if it is not null. That way you can achieve the desired result. If a is null then `dept1 = dept1` will be the condition which will be always true (if dept1 in your table is not null, That is altogether another scenario)

Cheers!!